# App not shown as top-level app in iOS Files Browser

Tags: ios, plist

I have an app "FooBar" with its `.plist` containing

```
        <key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
        <true/>
```

The documents stored within the app are shown under "On My iPhone/FooBar".

However, I'd also like "FooBar" to appear at the top-level list under "Locations".

Is there something else I need to add to the `.plist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it possible for your app to appear under "Locations" in the Files app, you need to include a FileProvider extension.
See [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/creating_a_file_provider_for_ios) for a starting point in the Apple documentation.